# php search engine filter

Tags: filter, search-engine

So I have this simple search engine which works perfectly, but now I want the user to select a region to search in, I added a field in the database table called location which holds an id of the region for each datarow in the table and when the user inserts id of the region in the input field when searching, the specific result will be shown according to the id, but I ran into problems with queries as my query maybe incorrect, I tested, the so called filter works to some extent, but it shows the two erros **Notice: Undefined index: userID in ...** and **Notice: Undefined index: name in ...** which I know it is because of the way I query, so:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is it possible to use one query which makes all the code work?

Thx everyone.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="text" name="location">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">search</button>
</form>
<?php
    require_once 'db.php';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        $search = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['search']);
        if ($search){
            if (isset($_POST["location"])){                 
                $location= $_POST["location"];                              
                $query = "SELECT * FROM shoplist WHERE name LIKE :search OR userID LIKE :search";
                $much = $muc->prepare($query);
                $much->bindValue(':search', '%' . $search . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $much = $muc->prepare('SELECT location from shoplist WHERE      location =:location');
                $much->bindParam(':location', $location);
                $much->execute();
                if ($much->rowCount() > 0) { 
                    $result = $much->fetchAll();  
                    foreach( $result as $row ) {
                       $userID = $row['userID'];
                       $name = $row['name'];
                       $location= $row['location'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As always simple things are the correct answer:

changed this:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM shoplist WHERE name LIKE :search OR userID LIKE :search";
            $much = $muc->prepare($query);
            $much->bindValue(':search', '%' . $search . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $much = $muc->prepare('SELECT location from shoplist WHERE      location =:location');
            $much->bindParam(':location', $location);
```

to this:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM shoplist WHERE location=:location AND (name LIKE :search OR userID LIKE :search)";
            $much = $muc->prepare($query);
            $much->bindValue(':search', '%' . $search . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $much->bindParam(':location', $location);
```